# How to access a shared folder on a PC with Windows Phone 8 API?

Tags: c#, networking, windows-phone-8

I need to show some images on an **app** only when the user double tap an item on a `LongListSelector`. The images are already in a folder on the server. What I wanted to do is concatenate the shared path **`[\\MachineName\Images\]`** with the name of the item. How can I associate the property source from an Image control with a shared path? 
All the images are JPEG files.

Answer (score 0):

From API it is impossible. API does not have direct access to the resources of PC.

And see this https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/accessing-shared-folder-using-wifi

Comment: Actually I need to build an app that access the files to display them in certain occassions.